# Multiple columns to datetime as an index without losing other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like this (except much longer). I want to convert to a datetime index.

```
      YYYY  MM  D   value
679   1900   1  1   46.42
1355  1900   2  1  137.14
1213  1900   3  1  104.25
1380  1900   4  1  149.39
1336  1900   5  1  130.33
```

When I use this

```
df = pd.to_datetime((df.YYYY*10000+df.MM*100+df.D).apply(str),format='%Y%m%d')
```

I retrieve a datetime index but I lose the value column. 
What I want in the end is -

```
             value
1900-01-01   46.42
1900-02-01   137.14
1900-03-01   104.25
1900-04-01   149.39
1900-05-01   130.33
```

How can I do this? 
Thank you for you time in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas to_datetime to convert this

```
df = df.astype(str)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY'] +' '+ df['MM']+' ' +df['D'])
df.drop(['YYYY','MM','D'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Out:

```
            value
1900-01-01  46.42
1900-02-01  137.14
1900-03-01  104.25
1900-04-01  149.39
1900-05-01  130.33
```